# alloca function in C

Tags: c, alloca

I was revising C and came across to alloca/free functions which is described as allocating storage on a stack like space. Is this same as the malloc/free ? or this is something different ? Thanks.

Comment: The following link suggests `alloc` is a different function: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/140380-k-r-5-6-stumped-again.html

Comment: I think you are right. I think its their example implementation of an allocator..

Comment: You're revising K&R?  You must be brilliant.

Comment: I know its 'a bit' outdated but dont know any other resources that can guide me through the basics. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you mean `alloca` which is used to allocate memory on the stack. And yes, this is different from `malloc` and `free` which allocate on the heap.

Don't attempt to free memory allocated with `alloca` because it is automatically freed when the function that calls `alloca` returns to its caller.

Using `alloca` and/or C99 variable length arrays can be a risky business because you can readily overflow the stack if you use these tools imprudently.

Comment: The third paragraph can't be stressed enough. There's almost no safe way to use `alloca` or VLAs.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` functions allocate space on the heap.

`free` function "frees" space previously allocated by these functions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some extra information to an old answer.

`malloc()` can be used for few reason, some of them are

1. Dynamic memory allocation
2. Scope (When one needs memory that stays between function calls)

But, one extra work that gets added with `malloc()` is we have to explicitly `free()` the allocated memory.

So, in order to use only the **Dynamic memory allocation** feature, and to avoid the overhead of `free()`, one can use `alloca()` in their program. This is made possible because memory is allocated on the stack (as mentioned by other answers) when `alloca()` is used.

Comment: @NickA I hope Haris did. I fixed it in any case.